# Are multiple synonyms.txt file allowed for a particular requesthandler?

Tags: solr

I have a requesthandler e.g /examplereqhandler and it retrieves data from a "examplereqhandler" core. Currently I have one synonyms.txt file which I use it through the SynonymFilterFactory.

Can we have multiple synonyms.txt for a particular request handler and can we assign weights to that file. e.g 70% from synonyms-1.txt and 30% from synonyms-2.txt.

Comment: What would assigning weights to synonyms mean? That if a synonym has been replaced, that synonyms is less worth than regular, original tokens?

Comment: @MatsLindh By assigning weights means like 70% of the time when users search a word then it should pick synonyms from synonyms-1.txt and 30% of the users should get synonyms from synonyms-2.txt. Require this for A/B Testing.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different field types with different synonym files, then select which field to use based on your frontend/controller code as this is where you know which A/B test to associate with the user (you'll have to use the same A/B value across requests, since different synonyms will affect which documents are being returned).

If you would do something like this in Solr, Solr would also have to have a way to communicate the result of which A/B test being picked back to you.

You might be interested in the [Learning to rank](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/learning-to-rank.html) functionality if you're going to take this further.