# A/B testing synonyms in Solr

Tags: solr, information-retrieval

How do I go about A/B testing synonyms in Solr.

I have two files `synonyms.txt` and `synonyms_to_test.txt`. I am using synonyms only during query time through SynonymGraphFilterFactory.

I already have a query analysis setup. Can I use multi-word synonyms in it? More on A/B test

- A could be a result of "cup => mug" in `synonyms.txt` say 24 items with cups and mugs
- B will be a result of "cup => mug, glass" in `synonyms_to_test.txt` say
  30 items with cups mugs, and glasses.
  I will then be measuring the click-through rate of B Vs A.

Note:

1. `synonyms.txt` is currently live in production
2. `synonyms_to_test.txt` has all the synonyms from `synonyms.txt` and some more.

I am looking for a way that doesn't involve adding a new field in the solr index.

An ideal solution will be to load `synonyms_to_test.txt` and send some parameters XYZ to Solr. Looking for XYZ if that makes sense.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487711/are-multiple-synonyms-txt-file-allowed-for-a-particular-requesthandler)

Comment: What do you mean by A/B-testing of synonyms? As what would be shown in the frontend? Synonyms in Solr is relevant for _querying_ and _searching_, and will not change the stored (or returned) text in any way. Are you trying to find out if "if I replace A with B, more people find the result relevant?" - in that case, how are you measuring relevancy? My initial thought is that you'll have to implement your own query analysis filter to achieve that.

Comment: I already have a query analysis filter.  How can I use multi-word synonyms in it?

More on A/B test

- *A* could be a result of "cup => mug" in `synonyms.txt` say 24 items with cups and mugs
- *B* will be a result of "cup => mug, glass" in `synonyms_to_test.txt` say 30 items with cups mugs, and glasses.

I will then be measuring the click-through rate of B Vs A.